# Set global variables to client only asp.net

Tags: asp.net, variables, client, global-variables

A while back I created a simple login form, which went to a database and pull down the information of the users logging on. Now I did this by using `global variables`; not realizing that they are server side variables not client side. So what happening is, say if I logged on on one computer, all other users using that site would be logged on as me.

So my question is.

> A) Is there a way to set the global variable to client side, so that
>   only the people using that pc are affected by the change in variables.
>
> B) Is there an alternatve to using global variables; so that i can
>   pass data between pages, like the global variable does.

I have tried using query strings. And although they work. They are a slight bit fiddly i find, as you have to parse them, and every time you leave each page; you have to send them to the new page.

Comment: Not sure if this would solve exactly what you are trying to do but have you tried using cookies?

Comment: You can use Session for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [ASP.NET session state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) will suit your needs pretty well. Another way is to use [cookies](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31914/Beginner-s-Guide-To-ASP-NET-Cookies) and it might be a better solution if you need to persist information for a given user across his *browser sessions*. But please note that cookies shouldn't be used for storing sensitive information (like passwords).

Comment: Hi, yes i like the look of this session variables. But one question, on the page_load event i want to get this session variable and add it to a string. But if the session variable is null (which it will be when i first go to the web site) it throws the error; due to the fact that it is null. What can i do about this, as with global variables, you declare it in the global.asx page, you can then check it on page_load, and it does not throw an error.

Comment: Nevermind, i have just put it in a try catch method. When the page loads, if there is not data it will not run it, the variable is only then declared on the click of a button. Which is read back into the label. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Create a class that holds all the user information that you retrieved from the database when the user logged in:

```
public class User {
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public int Id {get; set;}
}
```

Create a Session-level property that accesses the User property. This property should exist on each page that references the User object. Alternatively, you can create a base page that contains this property.

```
public User CurrentUser
{
   get {
      if(Session["User"] == null)
         return null;

      return (User)Session["User"];
   }
   set {
      Session["User"] = value
   }
}
```

Now, each time you reference this property, you just need to check if the object is null. If it is null, there is no logged-in user:

```
if(this.CurrentUser == null) {
   //no logged-in user
}
else {
   //the user is logged in
}
```